# Error while Login through Gmail Add Account Android

Tags: android, gmail, google-signin

In my app I have added gmail login. The login process is perfectly working in case of already added account mentioned in the screenshot provided in the attachment.

In case of Add new account as mentioned in the screenshot after adding all the detail of the user and allowing the account permission asked by google this is what the response google pass after login -

```
    Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}
```

This is my code for google login part

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

I event tried using requestIdToken, but still getting the same status code.

[image]